# MIME Message, missing fields in mail

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail-api, mime-message

I have this function MIME message that I then `POST` to google draft API. When manually checking in my drafts, the `mailContent` show's up properly.

```js
  const mailContent = req.body.content

  .
  .
  .


  var message = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
  'Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundaryboundary\r\n\r\n' +
  '--boundaryboundary\r\n' +
  'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
  mailContent + "\r\n\r\n" +
  '--boundaryboundary--';
```

Now I'm trying to add the `From`, `To` and `Subject` fields in my MIME message, and after quite some research, I thought that adding them to the 'body' like so would do the trick:

```js
  const mailContent = req.body.content
  const from = "exyleprod@gmail.com"
  const to = req.body.to || ""
  const subject = req.body.subject || ""
  .
  .
  .

  var message = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' +
  'Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundaryboundary\r\n\r\n' +
  'From: SomeName ' + '<' + from + '>' + "\r\n" +
  'To: ' + '<' + to + '>' + "\r\n" +
  'Subject: ' + subject + "\r\n" +
  '--boundaryboundary\r\n' +
  'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
  mailContent + "\r\n\r\n" +
  '--boundaryboundary--';
```

But it doesn't... I've tried logging the added fields and they are what I expect. The `POST` still work's and successfully create's an other draft with the `mailContent`. However, the 3 fields I'm trying to add don't show up. An I doing this wrong ?

Comment: Are you using Nodemailer to create the draft? If so you may want to check this [nodemailer documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way:

```js
var message = {
  from: "sender@example.com",
  to: "receiver@example.com",
  subject: "Message title",
  text: "Plaintext version of the message",
  html: "<p>HTML version of the message</p>"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundaryboundary\r\n\r\n, From: SomeName ${from}\r\n, To: ${to}\r\n, Subject: ${subject} \r\n --boundaryboundary\r\n Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n ${mailContent} \r\n\r\n --boundaryboundary--";
```

When using characters like "<>" as text, these characters can cause tags like "".
Do not use special characters such as "<>".